# Accessor for relation objects in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

this is my Category model:

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = ['id'];


public function media()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Media::class);
}

public function getMediaAttribute()
{
    return 'Foo';

    return ( ! is_null($this->media))
        ? $this->media
        : '/products/default/thumb.jpg';
}
```

and when i call it in route for get all object like this:

```
return \App\Category::with('media')->get();
```

it seems accessor not work and i can't get 'Foo' in category's media object

Comment: You can't have a `$this->media` relationship and a `$this->media` accessor simultaneously like this. One will override the other. (I don't remember which one takes precedence.)

Comment: so what can i do?

Comment: Jonas's `withDefault` is perfect here. In another scenario where that doesn't do exactly what you want, just rename one or the other - make the relationship `mediaRelationship` or the accessor `getMediaWithDefaultAttribute` or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `withDefault()`:

```
public function media()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Media::class)
        ->withDefault(['url' => '/products/default/thumb.jpg']);
}
```

When there is no result, it returns a `Media` instance with the given attributes.

Answer (score -1):

that's not how laravel accessors work

if you created it like

```
public function getMediaAttribute()
{
    return 'Foo';

    return ( ! is_null($this->media))
        ? $this->media
        : '/products/default/thumb.jpg';
}
```

then you will access it like:

```
return \App\Category::first()->media;
```

it will work as 'additional field' which can be manipulated in various ways for your model, in this case for the model category

more info on that:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

also as mentioned in the comment under your question, accessor with the same name as the relationship will override original field with given name, I'm not 100% sure the last part about overriding, that's how it works with mutators, I think it's same with accessors

Comment: NO! when i set getTitleAttribute() method for exmaple, it works. in this case i have set it on relation object, i think this problem it is

Comment: so yeah, the problem is with overriding, try with a different name, as I mentioned mutators are overriding other fields, I don't know how about accessors, I was 100% sure your syntax was wrong, my bad

Comment: i can't do this. because accessor name must exists

Comment: the accessor can have any name you want, there's no difference if you call it `getFooAttribute` or `getAasdsadadasAttribute` as long as you remember that name

Comment: when i try with different name it doesn't appear in object

Comment: try renaming it to `getFooAttribute`, then grabbing a single object from the query, like `$item = Category::first();` and then die it like `die($item->foo);` it should call this accessor

Comment: i wrote this code because i want to change media object when it hasn't value to default media like "no-image.jpeg". how can i do it?